# Spring Security Okta Registration Redirect Uri

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, kubernetes, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Have a spring boot mvc app protected by spring security oauth2 using authorization code flow . App is redirecting to proper redirect uri for login when deployed and running in local machine . But in our kubernetes deployment there is a api gateway in front of the app and app is accessed at following path

> ***https:///<k8_namespace_name>/<app_name>***

where
k8_namespace_name is the kubernetes namespace name and app_name is a identifier for the app in the namespace . Issue is that redirect uri for login is going to

> ***https:///oauth2/authorization/okta***

instead of

> ***https:///<k8_namespace_name>/<app_name>/oauth2/authorization/okta***

Below is the application.yaml config

```
 management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          okta:
            client-id: xxxxx
            scope:
              # Include the required openid scope
              - openid
              - employee_number
              - groups_whitelist
              - first_name
              - last_name
              - store_number
        provider:
          okta:
            authorization-uri: https://auth.com/v1/xxxx/authorize?skip_iwa=true
            token-uri: https://auth.com/v1/xxxx/token
            user-info-uri: https://auth.com/v1/xxxx/userinfo
            jwk-set-uri: https://auth.com/v1/xxx/keys
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `redirect-uri` property to define where user will be redirected after successful login.
It should look like that:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          okta:
            redirect-uri: https:///<k8_namespace_name>/<app_name>/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}
            client-id: xxxxx
            scope:
              # Include the required openid scope
              - openid
              - employee_number
              - groups_whitelist
              - first_name
              - last_name
              - store_number
        provider:
          okta:
            authorization-uri: https://auth.com/v1/xxxx/authorize?skip_iwa=true
            token-uri: https://auth.com/v1/xxxx/token
            user-info-uri: https://auth.com/v1/xxxx/userinfo
            jwk-set-uri: https://auth.com/v1/xxx/keys
```

Please remember to add your redirect uri to Okta client configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Issue is with redirect uri before successfull login . Currently to show the login page app is getting redirected to https://hostname/oauth2/authorization/okta , but i need the redirection to happen to https://hostname/<k8_namespace_name>/<app_name>/oauth2/authorization/okta

Comment: I think  i can add custom login path with http.oauth2Login().loginPage

Comment: @PradeepS do you want to display Okta login page or your own Custom login page?

Comment: @paweł-adamski, I'm using Keycloak instead of Okta, and I want to ask you where should I get this registrationId to use it for redirect-uri?

Comment: @elvis here you can find the answer https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2.html#oauth2login-sample-redirect-uri